# Filter out records with a pattern in R dataframe using dplyr with regex

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract only the records which has date in col1 and filter out other records. Problem is my variable does not have a fixed format of the data. So I am using regex on dplyr package in R with a pattern match. Able to filter the text data from the dataset. However not able to filter out the record which just have "2018".  Any help would be really appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(re)
library(stringr)
data1 <- data.frame( c( "sds_ds", "2018/01/11", "02/04/2018","2018"), c( 2018, 76, 35,45), c( 2017, 79, 38,46 ))
names(data1) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
data1

data1_clean = data1 %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(col1, pattern = "[a-z]"))
data1_clean
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are `filter`ing out rows that have only year in 'col1', an option is to negate

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% 
   filter(str_detect(col1, '[0-9/]'), 
          !stri_detect(col1, regex = "^[0-9]{4}$"))

#         col1 col2 col3
#1 2018/01/11   76   79
#2 02/04/2018   35   38
```

Comment: This brings the data with text as "sds_ds" which is not required.. It should show only 2 records in this example.. But I see your point .. Thank you.

Comment: @Akash Thanks, I didn't notice it.  Edited

Comment: Thanks to you.. I learnt another concept that we can pass multiple str_detect in the same filter with comma separator.

Answer (score 1):

We can define the regex based on the date format which we have and use it in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>% filter(grepl("[0-9]{2,4}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2,4}", col1))


#        col1 col2 col3
#1 2018/01/11   76   79
#2 02/04/2018   35   38
```

equivalent in base R

```
data1[grepl("[0-9]{2,4}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2,4}", data1$col1), ]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Here you are passing 2018, but it can be any year. Also I just want to have record 2nd and 3rd. And remove 1st and 4th record from my dataset.

Comment: @Akash updated the answer, see if it works for your case.